# Should Password strength meter and password guide used together

Tags: website-design, gui-design, signup-signon

I saw many sign up forms but none of them implemented both password strength meter and password guide together 
Currently validation in passwords are that it should be min. 8 characters with 1 special characters 1 upper case and 1 lower case.

So should I show both meter and guide on Ui on choose any one of them ?

Comment: Start by reading https://xkcd.com/936/

Answer (score 1):

As you have already stated yourself, both functionalities are complementary; it doesn't make much sense to show the strength meter without knowing what is required or entering a password without knowing whether the qualifications have been met.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't Set Users Up For Failure: Use Password Guides

Sites that have password restrictions such as minimum characters, required special characters and other restrictions but ***do not*** display a guide explaining these requirements are setting users up for failure.

Don't have users take a test they didn't study for only to see the answers after they fail. The NNGroup emphasizes this point in their recommendations for website form usability
(https://www.nngroup.com/articles/web-form-design/).

### Password Strength Meters Help

A password strength meter is not required, but it can be helpful. Its ability to show users the strength of their password reassures them that they are making their account secure. See Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs for the necessity for psychological safety.

If a password strength meter is shown, you should explicitly mark the minimum strength allowed for an acceptable password. Without this, the feedback mechanism fails.